# Need help with replacing bathroom exhaust fan

Tags: exhaust-fan, exhaust

Has anyone seen the outlet positioned this way before? Am I going to need to replace the whole box and rewire, or is there a replacement that will work?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. That looks like a very typical fan, with its integrated plug and outlet. When you replace it that whole thing goes away.

Comment: Depending on the problem, you may be able to purchase a replacement motor, though without taking the motor out and giving us some model numbers, it's tough to say.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Is this for an upgrade? That style is unfortunately old enough that I don't think anyone makes an upgrade kit for it, so you'll be stuck with like-for-like replacement to do repairs unless you want to replace the whole unit. Replacing the whole unit without a bunch of drywall work might be possible though. What is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and maybe.

With no specifics it's rather hard to tell about the latter.

I've certainly see fan motors powered by an outlet in the box - if you loosen, no need to remove, the two screws holding the bracket and twist so the bracket keyholes line up with the screw-heads, do the motor and fan drop out, [picture looks like is *should*] or is it one of those annoying interference fit fan-blade arrangements? Those can be changed out as well, but it's more annoying.